# Creating a rank variable by group for a binary response in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that includes year, month, and day variables and a dichotomous variable for heat wave(Yes=1, NO=0). I am trying to rank the heat waves from earliest date to latest date by year. If the heat wave variable =0 then I want to the rank variable to =0

This is what my data looks like and I would like to create the rank variable:

```
dd <- read.table(text="Year     Month     Day    HW    Rank
1999      5          2     0      0 
1999      6          1     1      1
1999      6          5     1      2 
2000      9          14    1      1
2000      9          15    0      0
2000      10         1     1      2 
2001      7          3     0      0
2001      7          24    1      1 
2001      8          12    1      2
2001      8          13    1      3", header=T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, assuming that the data.frame has been sorted properly by year, you can use `ave` and `cumsum` like this:

```
df$Rank2 <- with(dd, ave(HW, Year, FUN=function(x) cumsum(x) * x))
```

Here, `ave` groups the data by year, and performs the function `cumsum(x) * x` to each HW group. By multiplying by X, we set values of HW that are 0 to 0 regardless of the current value of `cumsum`. `with` is used to reduce typing.

Comment: I have `replace(ave(dd$HW, dd$Year, FUN = cumsum), dd$HW == 0, 0)` which, I think, is essentially the same

Comment: That is a pretty cool way to use the index argument of `replace`. If you want to post as a separate answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` you can do

```
dd %>% group_by(Year) %>% arrange(Year, Month, Day) %>% 
  mutate(Rank2=ifelse(HW!=0, cumsum(HW), 0))
```

Basically we just "add up" the number of HW flags you have for each given year.

Answer (score 1):

In the first part, we compute grouped `cumsum` like in [lmo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45199988/7128934). Then, we use `replace` to substitute `0` in the indices where `dd$HW` is `0`

```
replace(x = ave(dd$HW, dd$Year, FUN = cumsum), list = dd$HW == 0, values = 0)
# [1] 0 1 2 1 0 2 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: A little extra NSE with `transform`, and you can do `transform(dd, Rank3=replace(ave(HW, Year, FUN = cumsum), HW == 0, 0))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dd)[, Rank2 := cumsum(HW)*HW, Year]
dd$Rank2
#[1] 0 1 2 1 0 2 0 1 2 3
```